# Printing Odd and Even Elements of an Array

Tags: java, arrays, user-input

I'm trying to write a program that reads a sequence of integers and divide it into two sequences. The values on odd positions will be the first sequence and the values of even positions will be the second sequence. The program prints the elements of the first sequence and then the elements of the second sequence separated by a single space. The first input value specifies the number of elements.

Input: `7 1 2 4 5 6 8 9`

Expected Output: `1 4 6 9 2 5 8`

My Output: `2 0`

```
package twosequences;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TwoSequences {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int[] values = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i ++) {
        values[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
    int odd = 0;
    int even = 0;
    int i = 1;
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        even = values[i];
    } else {
        odd = values[i];
    }
    i++;
    System.out.printf("%d %d%n", odd, even);        
  }


}
```

I'm not sure why I'm outputting `2 0`. Any suggestions?

Comment: don't you want to add a loop around the `if ... else ... i++...` part?

Comment: i don't understand your expected output!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two different loops to iterate over even and odd elements respectively to obtain the desired output.

```
for (i = 0 ; i < n ; i += 2) {
    even = values[i];
    System.out.printf("%d ", even);
}
for (i = 1 ; i < n ; i += 2) {
    odd = values[i];
    System.out.printf("%d ", odd);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It will not produce the output OP wants.

Comment: @PM77-1 noted and edited. Thanks :)

Comment: @SajalNarang appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Print the even-numbered elements in one loop; then use another loop to print the odd-numbered elements.

```
System.out.print(values[0]); // print by itself to avoid prepending " ".
for (int i = 2; i < values.length; i += 2) {
  System.out.print(" " + values[i]);
}
for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i += 2) {
  System.out.print(" " + values[i]);
}
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 1):

you take the second element of an array (2), and only for that one you are checking if it's even or not. 
The result goes true for first 'if', and

```
even = 2;
```

, the if statement ends and odd stays as declares (0), that' why u got result like that. 
If you want output whith more than 2 integers, you need to change
, where n would be all scanned even numbers.
Try to put a counter in first for loop, like

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i ++) {
            values[i] = sc.nextInt();
            if(values[i]%2==0) evenCounter++;
        }
```

Now to count odds just count values.length - evenCounter.

Also you do not need to make simple arrays like int[], you can go with

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

You will be able to add elements in for loop withour knowing how many elements you will be implementing.

Hope some of those helps.